# Python 3 Miscellaneous Questions about lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two questions that aren't related, nor are they vitally important:

---

Question 1:

What is the order of single line declarations like `x,y = 1,2`? Is `x` declared first or is `y` declared first? This matters when `x` and `y` are, for example, related by reference.

---

Question 2:

Suppose I have a linkedList declaration like this:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

And I have a list of `ListNode` like:

```
lists = [1->2->3, 2->3->1, 0->9]
```

If I want to go ahead and compare the first value of each `ListNode` and find the smallest, I can do this:

```
smallest_index = 0
for index in range(len(lists)):
    if lists[index].val < lists[smallest_index].val:
        smallest_index = index
```

But is there a better way to do this? A more "elegant" way using built in functions to reduce the number of lines?

Comment: If you have more than one question you should ask them as more than one question

Comment: You can try the first one yourself: does `x, y = 0, x + 1` work?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "related by reference"?

Comment: it seems like both `x, y = 0, x + 1` and `y, x = x+1, 0` throws an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

They are effectively declared at the same time. If you want to make the value of one based on the other, you should not use a single line declaration.

Demo:

```
>>> x,y = 1,x+2    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> x,y = 1,y+2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

**Question 2**

You should generally prioritize readability over elegance but to answer your question there is another way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Note that this syntax `lists = [1->2->3, 2->3->1, 0->9]` is not valid so I did this instead: `lists = [ListNode(1),ListNode(2),ListNod(3)]`

```
from operator import attrgetter
min(nodes, key=attrgetter('val'))
```

This will return the ListNode with the lowest val. You can call `.val` on it to get the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, the assignment happens both at once and from left to right. At once from Python perspective and the environment in which you have access to and from left to right under the hood at bytecode level which you don't have access to. You can check this using `dis` module.

```
In [1]: x,y = 1,2

In [2]: import dis

In [3]: dis.dis('x,y = 1,2')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you an see, first at offset 6 the variable `x` is defined and then at offset 9 the `y`. But note that this doesn't mean that you can access to the new assignment at the same block. This is to say that in a code like `y, x = 9, y+1`  the value of `y` is it's value before the assignment (if it's already declared). The reason for this behavior is that what you see in disassembled bytecodes is what happens under the hood not at Python level and from your perspective the whole bytecode will be evaluated at once.

Regarding the second question you can use a generator expression within `min()` function:

```
min(lst.val for lst in lists)
```

If you want to return the `Node` object you can use `operator.attrgetter()` as the `key` function.

```
min(lists, key=attrgetter('val'))
```

Comment: Would `min(lst.val for lst in lists)` return the minimum `ListNode` or the minimum `ListNode.val`? I want to return the `ListNode` object, not the value.

Comment: @thestateofmay `ListNode.val`.

Comment: I'm testing `x, y = 0, x + 1` and `y, x = x+1, 0`, seems like they both throw a declaration error?

Comment: @thestateofmay That's because Python evaluates the codes at run time and when you execute a block of code they evaluates all at the same time from your perspective but from interpreter's perspective it's how it's showed in disassembled bytecodes.